# How to create a tag like in facebook in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to change "@name" to a href=/profile/name. i have used  regex,however I am not able to remove the '@'

```
w = re.compile(r"(@[^ ]+)")
w=w.sub(r'<a href=/profiles/"\1">\1</a>', content)
return w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get out of the symbol `@` from the capturing group. Because of the `@` present inside the capturing group, when you refer `\1`, it would print also the symbol `@` along with the user_name.

```
r = re.compile(r"@([^ ]+)")
```

OR

```
r = re.compile(r"@(\S+)")
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "hi @foo"
>>> r = re.compile(r"@([^ ]+)")
>>> r.sub(r'<a href=/users/"\1">\1</a>', s)
'hi <a href=/users/"foo">foo</a>'
```

Note that `re.sub` will replace all the matched chars with the chars inside the replacement part. So in the above example, `@foo` was replaced by `<a href=/users/"\1">\1</a>`. `\1` refers the string `foo`, since we captured only the text which exists next to the symbol `@`.

Comment: I am sorry...but i dont get what i should change in my code

Comment: change `re.compile(r"(@[^ ]+)")` to `re.compile(r"@([^ ]+)")`

Comment: tnx :)... the change was really minute...i couldnt see.....pretty complex these regex are